# In MVC3 how to get the top-level domain when begin a request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, request, uri, global-asax

My MVC3 application hosts many domains as

```
www.mysite.com 
www.mysite.de 
www.mysite.co.uk
...
```

Then, I have to get the top-level domain from the url (for example ".com") when begin a request; I have added the following code in Global.asax

```
Private Sub MvcApplication_BeginRequest(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.BeginRequest

    Dim toplevel_domain As String = Request.Url.Host
    toplevel_domain = toplevel_domain.Replace("www.", "").Substring(toplevel_domain.IndexOf(".") + 1, toplevel_domain.Length)

End Sub
```

However what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: `LastIndexOf` is a better option, if you just need the TLD. That's doesn't seem to be what you are doing, though.

Answer (score 0):

That's harder than you probably imagine in the general case. Don't forget that there are TLDs such as `co.jp`. So you could use a [`list of hardcoded TLDs`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VY3DCNhp) to look against.